# How to programmatically load database jar file into class path using class loader in java 9 app?

Tags: java-9

I have java app that loads the database driver jar file into the classpath with the following code

```
    for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++)
    {
         Method method = (URLClassLoader.class).getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[] {URL.class});
         method.setAccessible(true);
         method.invoke((URLClassLoader)ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(), new Object[] { new File(fileNames[i]).toURI().toURL() });
    }

    Class.forName(driverClassName); 
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(_url, _uid, _pwd);
```

This does not work with Java 9 because it gets a cast exception when casting system class loader to URLClassLoader.
How can you to do this in java 9?

Here is new code

```
String[] fileNames = m_dbDriverFileName.split(";");

URL[] path = new URL[fileNames.length];

for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++)
{
     path[i] = new File(fileNames[i]).toURI().toURL();
}

URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader(path, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
Class.forName(m_dbDriverClass, true, child);
```

Comment: The code fragment could potentially fail with ClassCastException in JDK 8 and older too, esp. when the system class loader is configured. In any case, the right thing to do is create a URLClassLoader that loads classes from the JAR file. If you could paste in a code fragment on how you specify the open the database connection then we can add see if other changes are needed -- you might have you change your TCCL for example so that the JDBC API can locate your driver.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: The driver is loaded with Class.forName(driverClassName);   con = DriverManager.getConnection(_url, _uid, _pwd);

Comment: So why can't you create a URLClassLoader and pass that class loader to Class.forName to load the driver class?

Comment: I am getting "No suitable driver found".  I added my new code above

Comment: Did DriverManager.register work?

Comment: I am calling DriverManager.getConnection(url, uid, pwd).  That is what is failing with no suitable driver found.

Comment: If you aren't using register then are you setting the thread context class loader before calling getConnection? I believe this is what JDBC needs in order to find your driver loaded by a custom class loader.

Answer (score 4):

On Java 9 [the system class loader is no longer a `URLClassLoader`](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-9-migration-guide/#Casting-To-URL-Class-Loader) (which was never specified anyway - that was an implementation detail) and it is not possible to append JARs to the class path at run time.

You should instead create a new class loader, e.g. a `URLClassLoader`, with the desired path and the system class loader as parent. For more details you should extend your question to show how you go on to load the driver.

Comment: The driver is loaded with Class.forName(driverClassName);